# JMeter - How to run two thread group concurrently?

Tags: java, api, rest, jmeter

I have two thread group:

1. Authentication Thread Group
2. REST API Thread Group.

In the first thread group(Authentication Thread Group) I will be generating "access token" using "refresh token" using HTTP request and using JSON parser "access token" is taken. The access token is passed to second thread group(REST API Thread Group) using Inter thread communicator.

The passed access token is used for authenticating the REST APIs in REST API Thread Group.

Using Flow Control Action I had set the Authentication Thread Group to run on interval, so that I can get the new "access token" before it gets expired. Now I am trying to run REST APIs with the current "access token".

So basically I want to run RESP APIs with its respective Thread Group logic, meanwhile the authentication Thread Group has to be executed for given delay time.

Suggest a way to achieve the above?
Alternate solution for authenticated REST API is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special box in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) which allows JMeter to run Thread Groups at the same time:

[image]

if you **untick** it - JMeter will run all the Thread Groups in parallel.

Apart from this your "way to achieve the above" is correct.

Alternative solution would be switching to JMeter Properties from the Inter-Thread Communication plugin, i.e. :

- use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to convert the token into JMeter Property in "Authentication" thread group
- use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the token in the API thread group

check out [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) guide for more details.

Comment: I think i am missing something, as the jmx is not working as expected.

Comment: Used setproperty() instead of Inter Thread communication. 
Run Thread Groups consecutively option is disabled.
Then REST API Thread Group has been delayed with startup delay option in specify thread life time check box option.
Then it worked for me.